# Solder QFN88 by Hand

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, production, qfn

I just received my newest board i've designed and wanted to solder the first prototype.

One of my Chips has a QFN88 Footprint. I'm quite experienced, but i just couldn't do it. Because of the small pitch, there are always short circuits.

I tired adding tin to pads and pins, and heat everything with the "hot air rework tool". When this didn't worked i tried to add solderpaste with the stencil i ordered, and placed the Chip by hand. Also didn't work. The chip was blown away by the "hot air rework tool".

Has anyone a tip on how to solder QFN88 by hand? 
I'm glad the production will be done using a P&P machine.

Comment: This is a bit broad and there are plenty of existing questions on the topic.  Generally though, you should expect shorts in the initial installation if it is done by hand, then go and remove them with ultra fine solder braid.  And you don't want a "heat gun" which is a device for stripping paint, but rather a "hot air rework tool" which is adjustable to low airflow rates.

Comment: The pads should be longer than normal for hand soldering with an iron. Drag solder. It takes flux the right amount of solder and not too much finesse in order to not bridge. Hot air though? I don't use it so don't know.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I use a "hot air rework tool", just didn't know how to name it... I might have to get a finer solder wick tough. What is generally better: Heating the pcb from the Component side or from underneath?

Comment: Is this leadfree?

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, but i also have tin with lead

Comment: Use that stuff instead. You probably need a preheater with leadfree

Comment: Put some glue under the chip to hold it in place, or if it has a pad, you can just tack 4 of the corner pins with a solder pencil then hot-air the rest without it blowing away. You can also turn the air flow down and work slower.

Comment: I would personally recommend against glue except as a latch ditch for badly designed pads.  Surface mount parts work on surface tension, and if left to their own devices with a good land pattern and flux will seek the ideal position.  If they're "off by one" just bump them with the tweezers while they're floating on the molten solder and they'll snap over to the right alignment.  Sometimes if a pad isn't wetting bumping the chip around a bit will help get things going.

Comment: If the chip blows away when you use a hot-air rework tool, then you have the air blowing too strong and/or you're holding it too close to the board. Back off a bit and use more patience - you need to heat the whole chip, board & solder paste evenly together.

Comment: Tacking the device on two corner pins allows you to position it correctly and limit any 'leaf in a storm' tendencies